# timestamp of the last hit of an iptables rule

Tags: iptables

I am looking for a way to get timestamps of `iptables` rules' last hits for a long-running instance. (I know of the `recent` module and `iptables -vL` etc., but they serve a different purpose.) I have spent some time searching now, including here, and most answers and man pages talk about packet/byte counts for each rule, or how to dynamically control IP sets and update the rules based on the count and recency of the source packets and not when a given rule was last hit.

I have an installation where I need to check when certain rules that have non-zero packet counts were last hit and remove them if it was long ago. Is there any way of getting this information out?

Comment: You just dismissed the recent match, while it would probably have been given as a possibility for this. You should describe why you consider it can't be used.

Comment: First, the vast majority of the rules in place don't have it, nor need to use it. Second, if I match on a recent packet and e.g. to temporarily block it for X amount of time due to a scan, and then auto-unblock later, this would not tell me if this rule as a whole was used yesterday or 6 months ago. Unless I am missing something.